# Compare matching data and extract associated value

Tags: excel, match

Here is what I have.
Col A has a list of product numbers
Col D has a list of product numbers
Col E has an associated value with Col d

I would like to run through the col A list and if the same product number is found in Col D, take the associated value in Col E and place in Col C ( which is empty)
Ther are about 9500 lines items in Col A

Any assistance in anyway would be appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: An example would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP, in C1:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE),"")
```

If you have column labels in the first row, then change the `A1` to reference the correct row.

Then drag/copy down the column.

Comment: two easy.  CAn you let me know what the FASE in the formula is doing ?

Comment: @DubMartian It is looking for an exact match.  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done,  Thank you kindly!!